# FDT: Is there a good workflow to follow if I'm building Haxe / NME project with FDT

Tags: workflow, haxe, fdt

FDT is a great editor for Haxe as of the release of FDT 5.5, however I'm still learning the best workflows for compile and testing my project.

There is a tone of buzz around using NME / NMML files to make it easier for cross platform compilation and testing.

I found that when using sublime text 2 I could do the following in my hxml config.

```
-cmd nme test build.nmml flash
```

If I add nmml file to my FDT project I'm wondering if there is a easy way to have the nmml commands to there thing and launch the swf as I usually test code in Flash player first. It would be nice if this could be done somehow in a debug configuration as I would still like to use breakpoints and other things like the console trace statements.

If there is really no way the I suppose the best option is to test as normal using swf compilation and then hope over to the command line to run the nmml commands ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best thing I've found so far sense there really isn't "Native" NME support in FDT yet.

https://github.com/matthewswallace/FDT-Haxe-project-templates